# Upgrade Magento from 2.2.4 to 2.3.7

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, magento-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Magento from 2.2.4 to 2.3.7

I got a lot of errors, so i fixed them by changing module's version, now

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.7  --no-update
composer update
```

I got those errors

```
Problem 1
- magento/project-community-edition 2.2.1 requires magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7 requires temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping[2.0.0].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7 requires temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping[2.0.0].
- temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 requires temando/module-shipping-remover 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping-remover[1.0.0].
- temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 requires temando/module-shipping-remover 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping-remover[1.0.0].
- don't install temando/module-shipping-remover 1.0.0|remove magento/project-community-edition 2.2.1
- remove magento/project-community-edition 2.2.1|remove temando/module-shipping-remover 1.0.0
- Installation request for magento/project-community-edition 2.2.1 -> satisfiable by magento/project-community-edition[2.2.1].
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.7].
```

I changed the version in composer.json to 2.3.7 (for magento/project-community-edition) and i got installation started but then stopped with error

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                           
 Package is not installed: magento/project-community-edition-2.3.7.0
```

Edit, i updrated Composer to version 2 i got those errors

```
 Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires fooman/printorderpdf-m2 ^3.3, it is  satisfiable by fooman/printorderpdf-m2[3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2] from  composer repo (https://repo.packagist.org) but fooman/printorderpdf- m2[3.1.0] from artifact repo (/home/wetag/public_html/vendor/fooman /packages) has higher repository priority. The packages with higher priority do not match your constraint and are therefore not installable. See https://getcomposer.org/repoprio for details and assistance.
Problem 2
- magento/project-community-edition is present at version 2.2.1  and cannot be modified by Composer
- temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 requires temando/module-shipping-remover 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping-remover[1.0.0].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7 requires temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping[2.0.0].
- temando/module-shipping-remover[1.0.0] cannot be installed as that would require removing magento/project-community-edition[2.2.1]. They both replace temando/module-shipping-m2 and thus cannot coexist.
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.7].
```

Comment: your composer version?

Comment: @kanidhaya 1.10.22

Comment: In 2.3.7 needs composer version 2 please update your composer version then try it will fix

Answer (score 0):

for magento 2.3.7 Needs  composer version 2
please upgrade your composer version 2
`composer self-update --2` then try it it will fixed

Comment: i updated my question with the errors after upgrading composer

Comment: after upgrade did u run composer update in your magento root folder?

Comment: yes i did, i upgrated composer to version 2 and after i runned composer update